# How to exclude users that the current user is already following from the discover page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to exclude users that are already followed within the discover page. Upon page load, the users that the `current_user` has followed should be removed from the discover page. So far I have managed to exclude `current_user` from the discover page with:

```
def User.all_except(user)
  where.not(id: user)
end
```

Albeit not too sure how to implement the phasing out of followed users from the discover page.

Is it similar to the above code were from the relationship model `followed_id` should be picked out as follows?:

```
 Relationship.where.not(follower_id: user.id)
```

Comment: there is a complete guide present for followers and followings. It may help you out :)
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the field names are correct, but given you have a model Relationship with columns follower_id and followed_id it should be something like:

```
User.where.not(id: Relationship.where(follower_id: user.id).select(:followed_id))
```

It will generate a subquery like that:

> SELECT ... FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT following_id FROM ...)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why pluck is more efficient? pluck will generate 2 queries - first query will return all the ids and second will contain those ids as a list.
But select will generate a query and it is more efficient then passing long list of ids twice.

Comment: I just tested and I'll be damned, it _does_ indeed generate a subquery. TIL, thanks

Comment: It was actually a Relationship model with ```follower_id``` and ```followed_id``` columns. Thanks, it works like a charm.

Comment: @AlexKeene do you have an idea of how I can include ```current_user``` from the exclusion within the same method?

Comment: @ThatoSello I doubt you can add it to the subquery. I would just add one more where:

`User.where.not(id: Relationship.where(follower_id: user.id).select(:followed_id)).where.not(id: user.id)`